# Data file not being read

Tags: vba, parsing, file-io, populate

This is my code:

```
Open "Data.txt" For Input As #1

N = 1

While Not EOF(1)

  ReDim DataName(N)
  ReDim Data(N, Max_Time_Point)
  ReDim line(N)

  Input #1, line(N)
  DataName(N) = Split(line(N))(0)
  For j = 1 To Max_Time_Point
      Data(N, j) = Split(line(N))(j)
      Debug.Print "data", N, j, Data(N, j)
  Next j
  N = N + 1
Wend
```

And Data.txt looks like this

```
First 7 3 1 4 8
Seconds 3 6 10 5 4
...
```

My problem is that the debug statement prints out what I expect, that the data is filled into the matrix Data(). But when I exit the loop, Data() only has its last line populated (The last line of data, which for Data.txt just goes to line six). What is going on?

EDIT: I think I've found the problem--I think it's the ReDim statement resetting all values to 0.

Comment: You need to use `ReDim Preserve`

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
ReDim Data(N)
```

with

```
ReDim Preserve Data(N)
```